# For $u \in C[0,1]$ with $u(0)=u(1)=0$ show $\int_0^1 u^2(x) dx \leq C\int_0^1 (u'(x))^2 dx$

Tags: integration, functional-analysis

Let $u$ be a continously differentiable function of the interval $[0,1]$ s.t $u(0)=u(1)=0$ show there exists a constant $C$ so the following hold $\int_0^1 u^2(x) dx \leq C\int_0^1 (u'(x))^2 dx$.

I'm not sure where to go with this problem I tried starting by using the fundamental theorem of calculus and could get anywhere.

Comment: It is called Wirtinger's inequality. See "second version" here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger%27s_inequality_for_functions

Comment: Hint: Use fourier expansion and apply parseval's theorem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Zeekless said, you can get $C=\frac{1}{\pi^2}$ using Wirtinger's inequality.

On the other hand, it is possible to bound it (by a worse constant) using FTC. Writing
$$ u(x)^2=\left( \int_0^x u'(t) \mathrm{d} t \right)^2 \leq \left(\int_0^x u'(t)^2 \mathrm{d} t\right) \left( \int_0^x 1^2 \mathrm{d} t\right) \leq \int_0^1 u'(t)^2 \mathrm{d}t,$$
you get $C=1$, after integrating from $x=0$ to $1$.